# Cannot create Virtual IP using the SoftLayer API

Tags: api, rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When using the API to place an order for a VIP, it is failing with a non intuitive error message. Please see the following REST API call JSON and the ensuing error:

```
JSON:
{
  "loadBalancer": {
    "name": "lbName_TEST",
    "id" : 123, 
    "type": "HTTP",
    "sourcePort": 80,
    "virtualIpAddress": "123.123.123.123"
  }
}

REST API URL USED:
https://user.name:longid4235234532@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller/15293/createLiveLoadBalancer.json

{
  "error": "Invalid port supplied.",
  "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
}
```

The question that arises is this. We are trying to script the ordering of a VPX Netscaler and the addition of all related configurations to the created VPX, are we doing something out of order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to create the loadBalancer the JSON is wrong, try this JSON:

```
{
"parameters": [
    {
         "name": "lbName_TEST",
         "type": "HTTP",
         "sourcePort": 80,
         "virtualIpAddress": "123.123.123.123",
         "loadBalancingMethod": "pi"
    }
]
```

}

Regards

Comment: I think I'm almost there, however I am getting a new error;

    {
      "error": "Operation not permitted",
      "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
    }

I'm using the public IP that is returned when I perform "https://{{userName}}:{{apiKey}}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller/1xxxx/getObject.json" that is ""primaryIpAddress": "1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"" which is what I was assuming is the Public IP that is associated with my VPX when I initially placed the order (just 1 IP to test with).

Comment: It worked fine for me, please make sure that you are using a valid virtualIPAddres and loadBalacing method.

Comment: I think this is where the confusion on my part is coming in to play. In the sldn virtualIpAddress is defined as: "virtualIpAddress
The virtual, public-facing IP address for your load balancer. This is the address of all incoming traffic", when I created the VPX, and perform a getObject on the VPX I see "primaryIpAddress" but no virtual IP. I'm just showing "123.123.123.123" to mask our private data but the IP I am using is a valid public IP. Thoughts?

Comment: Well the Virtual IP address must be different from the "primary Ip Address" that you got using the getObject. The IP addres that you  will pick out for the VIrtualIP addres must belong to the same VLAN as your netscaler belong. You can try first to create the load balancer manually (In the portal select the netscaler device click in actions and select manage device) and then try via API using the same configuration

Comment: Thanks @Nelson!, that did it, I really wish this stuff was documented better but having good folks like you to help out almost makes up for it.

Answer (score 0):

To order a device or service, you need to use the SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder method. here an example to order a NetScaler

```
URL: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder

Method: POST

PAYLOAD: {
    "parameters": [
        {
            "packageId": 192,
            "location": 265592,  
            "prices": [
                {
                    "id": 22315,
                    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price"
                },
                {
                    "id": 17238,
                    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price"
                }
            ],
            "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller"
        }
    ]
}
```

The price 22315 is for a "Citrix NetScaler VPX 10.1 10Mbps Standard" and the 17238 is for "2 Static Public IP Addresses"
To get all the prices use  the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItems method

Comment: Hi Nelson, 
I'm sorry I think I was unclear in asking my question. We have already ordered the VPX device using the placeOrder method. The problem is now we need to also create the things that make it work, starting with the createLiveLoadBalancer method. That method is what is throwing the error.